# css for centering on mobile issue

Tags: html, css

On a large screen my phone number is to the left of the logo. That is working fine.
On a smaller screen, I would like the phone number centered under the logo. That is not working.

This is not working for me:

This is an update. But I don't think padding-right is the correct solution.

```
<style>
  @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .phone { text-align: center; 
     padding-right:70px;

   }
     </style>

   <h3 class="phone" style="float:right;margin-top:30px;"><a href="mailto:info@elementive.com">info@elementive.com</a> | 720-897-8705</h3>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "That is not working." How _is_ it rendering?

Comment: in smaller screen, it is under the logo but it is still floating right. I need it to center in small screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing the dot(.) from your class selector.

```
<style>
  @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

     h3.phone {

      text-align: center;

      clear: both;

      padding: 20px 0 0;

      float: none;

    }

   }
 </style>
```

Also the `span` is an inline element, whilst the `<h3>` is a block element so you should aether add the span to the h3 or just use the class and styles you've applied to it on the `<h3>` tag!

Comment: "did you try turning it off then on?"

Comment: Hi, I added the dot but it still isn't centered on small screen.

Comment: remove the span altogether and use the class and styles on your `<h3 class="phone" style="float:right;margin-top:30px;">` as it's a block element it will take up 100% width and center the text within it.

Comment: Hi, I added a padding-right..phone { text-align: center; 
padding-right:70px; Do you think everyone will see it centered? I do, but I am not sure

Comment: If that works for you and your site isn't responsive it will look correct for all... One more thought, do you have any `float:` type styles added to the `.phone` selector elsewhere in your stylesheet?

Comment: Hi, no I don't. I am viewing on screenfly too so there are slight variations...sometimes it is not completely centered.

Comment: can you post a link, Ill take a look.